# NSLog: Thread Error

Tags: objective-c

Error in NSLog:

```
*** -[NSThread initWithTarget:selector:object:]: target does not implement selector (*** -[Document myTcpClient])
```

code:

```
-(void) myTcpStart: (NSButton*) button{   
    //need threads for the following
    thread_Client = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(myTcpClient) object:nil];
    thread_Display = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(displayData) object:nil];

    [thread_Client start];
    [thread_Display start];

    [textField1 setStringValue:@"waiting for threads to run"];
}


-(void) myTcpStop: (NSButton*) button{   
    //need threads for the following

    //[thread_Client cancel];
    //[thread_Display cancel];
}

-(void) displayData{
    while(1){   
        [textField1 setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %d %f", j, i, genValue]];
        j++;
    }
}

-(void) myTcpClien{
    //some code
}
```

header file:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Document : NSDocument
{
    NSTextField *textField1;
    int i;
    int j;
    double genValue;
    NSWindowController *bController;
    NSThread *thread_Client;
    NSThread *thread_Display;
}

-(void) myTcpClient;
-(void) displayData;

-(void) myTcpStart: (NSButton*) button;
-(void) myTcpStop: (NSButton*) button;

@end
```

Comment: An obvious question would be: have you implemented (not declared, like you showed us) `-myTcpClient`?

Comment: You should be seeing compiler warnings that your class doesn't implement all the methods it declares. Please heed these warnings! They are not spurious.

Comment: what do you mean?  It is there

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out that AppKit controls don't take kindly to being updated from threads other than the main thread. Expect your implementation of -displayData to cause crashes that look like they come from nowhere as well as deadlocks and general strangeness.

Comment: @jdl you spelled it wrong in the implementation file. You forgot the t at the end. See my answer.

Comment: Ya... displayData shows data for awhile and then blanks out or locks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the T in myTcpClient implementation. Again when you see these messages check your code for spelling errors.

Change:

```
- (void)myTcpClien { /* ... */ }
```

To:

```
- (void)myTcpClient { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: And read the error messages carefully.  The message was telling you exactly what was wrong.

Comment: @Jason, what is a better way of displaying data to the screen... if I can't do it in this thread?  If I do it in the main thread... nothing everything else happens.